# Redirect to non-www going in infinite loop

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have problem with my htaccess redirecting to non www.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www.)?example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

It is creating an infinite loop,

How can i redirect to non- www without redirect error?.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess is redirecting both versions (www/non-www) of your site to non-www, that's why it creates an infinite loop.

Try this to redirect only the "www" version to "non-www".

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Explaination :**

`^www\.example\.com$` The anchors `^` and `$`   mean this is the complete string in `HTTP_HOST` variable, nothing before or after. Therefore, if the domain name passed with the request matches `www.example.com` then the entire URI string matched in regex pattern `^(.*)$` is redirected to `example.com`, thereby stripping off the `www.` from the front.